# Feature importance on regression models (DecisionTreeRegressor, IsotonicRegression, GBTRegressor)

Tags: apache-spark-mllib

In my spark ml application. I am using several regression models such as DecisionTreeRegressorModel,LinearRegressionModel,RandomForestRegressorModel,GBTRegressorModel,AFTSurvivalRegressionModel,IsotonicRegressionModel.

I need to get the feature weights of all these models when they train a sample tarning set..looking at documentation for Spark MLib 1.6.2 it seems only LinearREgressionModel,AFTSurvivalRegression and RandomForestRegressorModel give me some parametres to extract feature weights. The linearregressionmodel and AFTSurvivalRegression  gives me feature "coefficient" and the Random Forest give me "feature importance".

what are about other models such as DecisionTreeRegressor, GBTRegressor, IsotonicRegression? Can I get any feature importance parameters from those model on a trained sample as well?